# Swift format invalid URLs to valid ones

Tags: ios, swift, string, url

I would like to refractor *invalid* `URLs` to *valid* ones **if possible**, otherwise just return an empty `String`.

Here are 5 examples:

> Call me by your name
> https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07B58SGWP/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_fabc_iCJ6Fb0QVVW8Y?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1

> https://farfetch.onelink.me/yQyB/b9f5e5d2?af_dp=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.farfetch.com%2Fshopping%2Fitem-16119737.aspx&af_web_dp=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.farfetch.com%2Fitem-16119737.aspx Shoppen Golden Goose 'Hi Star' Sneakers

> Schau dir LANDSKRONA von IKEA an. Hier noch weitere Informationen:
> https://ingka.page.link/gqV9dAw61TqNJrne9

> [https://www.amazon.de/DALLE-PIANE-CASHMERE-Anthrazit-Einheitsgröße/dp/B06XY2ZGBZ/ref=mp_s_a_1_13_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=dalle%2Bpiane%2Bcashmere%2Bschal&qid=1610091194&sprefix=dalle%2Bpia&sr=8-13-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExT0hHOFRLWElYVUJBJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwOTY1ODUyOUJWWUU4MlY0SVUwJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA0ODk2NzEzSDZNSUJOR1haREVTJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfcGhvbmVfc2VhcmNoX210ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU&th=1](https://www.amazon.de/DALLE-PIANE-CASHMERE-Anthrazit-Einheitsgr%C3%B6%C3%9Fe/dp/B06XY2ZGBZ/ref=mp_s_a_1_13_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=dalle%2Bpiane%2Bcashmere%2Bschal&qid=1610091194&sprefix=dalle%2Bpia&sr=8-13-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExT0hHOFRLWElYVUJBJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwOTY1ODUyOUJWWUU4MlY0SVUwJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA0ODk2NzEzSDZNSUJOR1haREVTJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfcGhvbmVfc2VhcmNoX210ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU&th=1)

> [https://www.apple.com/de/shop/buy-ipad/ipad-air/64gb-grün-wifi](https://www.apple.com/de/shop/buy-ipad/ipad-air/64gb-gr%C3%BCn-wifi)

So I tought about it and I would need a function that strips down a `String` to the actual `URL` only ( first three examples )  but also refractor the ones with letters that can't be in a  valid `URL`. I am mostly struggling with the second one. I don't quite get why these can't be regactored in a `valid` Swift URL even if they can be opened in a normal Webbrowser...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Chris, that's not how you should do it! In any case at the first place, _avoid to create_ invalid URL strings on the backed or in any primary source (for example a human that types a URL string manually into a text input field in a form etc.). Any "fix" on the client side can only be a brittle bandaid that may work today, but not in a week later. So, on the client side you should net obtain syntactically invalid URLs.

Comment: i know, I am avoiding it now. but there are some bad urls in my database already and I need to change them. There are not many of them, maybe 50-100. But I need to change them.

Comment: and also, right now all these 5 examples would not be valid in my app so the user would get prompted with some error message. But that's not exactly what I want since there are actually valid URL's in the examples, I just need to extract them. I hope I am making sense here @CouchDeveloper :D

Comment: The first 3 ones, would be : `let candidateURL = thatString.components(separator: .whiteSpacesAndNewLines).first(where: { URL($0) != nil })`, not tested against a compiler though.

Comment: If this DB is on the backend, well, just print out all invalid URLs. Extract the wrong path component manually, then use a tool to apply proper percent encoding. If the amount is less than a 20 or 100, you may be finished before you try to solve it with a script.

Comment: Can we assume that ALL your URLs are at least starting with "http"? That your extension does so? If so, you might use something like that https://pastebin.com/ipbmd0Fr (raw testing in Playground)

Comment: @Larme yes you can assume that. What should I do with pastebin?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I might do that but in the future I would like to be able to refractor the urls. Let's say one of the examples is given be a user, then it should not just say **invalid url** but instead it should try to make it a valid one, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, is to try to find an URL.
Let's separate each "subelement", then test each subelement, and try to percent escape invalid characters.

```
func findingPossibleURL(in string: String) -> URL? {
    let components = string.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let possibleURLs = components.compactMap { aCandidate -> URL? in
        if let range = aCandidate.range(of: "http") {
            let candidate = String(aCandidate[range.lowerBound...])
            if let asSuch = URL(string: candidate) {
                return asSuch
            } else {
                if let percentEscaped = candidate.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) {
                    return URL(string: percentEscaped)
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    return possibleURLs.first
}
```

Sample use:

```
let stringToTest = ...
if let url = URL(string: stringToTest) {
    //That's the URL
} else if let url = findingPossibleURL(in: stringToTest) {
    //That's the URL
} else {
    //We couldn't find a URL
}
```

Testings:

```
let tests = ["Call me by your name https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07B58SGWP/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_fabc_iCJ6Fb0QVVW8Y?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1",
             "https://farfetch.onelink.me/yQyB/b9f5e5d2?af_dp=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.farfetch.com%2Fshopping%2Fitem-16119737.aspx&af_web_dp=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.farfetch.com%2Fitem-16119737.aspx Shoppen Golden Goose 'Hi Star' Sneakers",
             "Schau dir LANDSKRONA von IKEA an. Hier noch weitere Informationen: https://ingka.page.link/gqV9dAw61TqNJrne9",
             "https://www.amazon.de/DALLE-PIANE-CASHMERE-Anthrazit-Einheitsgröße/dp/B06XY2ZGBZ/ref=mp_s_a_1_13_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=dalle%2Bpiane%2Bcashmere%2Bschal&qid=1610091194&sprefix=dalle%2Bpia&sr=8-13-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExT0hHOFRLWElYVUJBJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwOTY1ODUyOUJWWUU4MlY0SVUwJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA0ODk2NzEzSDZNSUJOR1haREVTJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfcGhvbmVfc2VhcmNoX210ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU&th=1",
             "https://www.apple.com/de/shop/buy-ipad/ipad-air/64gb-grün-wifi",
             "hello world",
             "",
             "Gerade entdechttps://www.zalando.at/adidas-originals-tight-leggings-hosen-blackwhite-ad121a0er-q11.html"]
tests.forEach { aTest in
    print("Testing: \(aTest)")

    if let url = URL(string: aTest) {
        print("Found URL: \(url)")
    } else if let url = findingPossibleURL(in: aTest) {
        print("Found URL: \(url)")
    } else {
        print("NO URL FOUND")
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like a good solution for the first three examples! But what abouht the last two? These are actually valid URLs but because of an "ü" for exaples, my textView fails... Any idea on how to refractor these ?

Comment: Did you run the tests, and then copy/paste the output in your webbrowser? It percent escape it, making it valid URL objects, and yet they point to the correct webpage. I can't guarantee that it will work for all, but at least these one.

Comment: I think it is working, there is actually one more case thats missing. One completely String containing a valid String, e.g. : "Gerade entdechttps://www.zalando.at/adidas-originals-tight-leggings-hosen-blackwhite-ad121a0er-q11.html" .

Comment: so one more `else if` case to check if  given `String` *contains*  a valid `URL`

Comment: Update answer should manage that case now. If all url start with "http". If that's not the case, it harder.

Comment: one small issue I had to fix was also putting `, urlSafe.starts(with: "http")` after the `if let url = URL(string: urlSafe)` . Otherwise "testhttps://www.google.de/?client=safari" would return it with "test" at the beginning. Now  everything is workin as expected, thanks!